# How do I add different levels & a quit option to my guess a number game?

Tags: python

So I'm a freshman in high school trying to figure out Python coding, and I need to make a guess a number game.

My first level works fine, but I need to make it so it has 3 different levels, and a quit option. I don't understand these while loops.

I'm really sorry if I posted something wrong or this is an already asked question, but any help would be much appreciated!

Here's my code so far:

```
import random
print("let's play guess a number!")
myLevel=int(input("would you like to play level 1, 2, 3, or quit?"))

if myLevel == 1:
    number1= random.randit(1,10)
    guess1=int(input("guess an integer from 1 to ten"))

while number1!=guess1:
    print
    if guess1<number1:
                 print("guess is too low")
                 guess1=int(input("guess again! or would you like to quit?"))
                 #this is where i want to be able to quit
    elif guess1>number1:
                 print("guess is too high!")
                 guess1=int(input("guess again! or would you like to quit?"))
                 #this is where i want to be able to quit
    if guess1==number1:
                print("you guessed it!")

if myLevel == 2:
nextumber2= random.randint (1,100)
guess2=int(input("guess an integer from 1 to 100"))

while number2!=guess2:
print

if guess2<number2:
        print("guess is too low!")
        guess2=int(input("guess again!"))
elif guess2>number2:
        print("guess is too high!")
        guess2=int(input("guess again!"))

print("you guessed it!")
```

Comment: Your code indentation doesn't look right

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Python! Since you're new I'll go over the fundamentals of everything you need to learn to complete this game.

Your code looks good so far. Since your question is mainly about a while loop, you'll need to learn what exactly that does. A while loop is a block of code that first checks the provided condition, then executes the indented code block if the condition evaluates to true. Then, it checks the condition again, and executes the code again if it's still true. This continues until the condition evaluates to false.

```
x = 0
while x < 5:
    print(x)
    x += 1
```

Try this code out. It should print 0 to 4 then stop when x = 5.

What's actually happening:

```
x = 0

# loop starts here
if x < 5: #true
    print(x)
    x += 1
if x < 5: #true
    print(x)
    x += 1
if x < 5: #true
    print(x)
    x += 1
if x < 5: #true
    print(x)
    x += 1
if x < 5: #true
    print(x)
    x += 1
if x < 5: #false
    # At this point, x is not longer < 5, so the repeating stops and the code continues to run as normal.
```

Imagine if you wanted to print numbers from 1 to 50. Would you rather have a loop, or do each number by hand like the above? In fact, if you want to print from 1 to x, where you don't know what x will be beforehand, you'll need a loop!

While loops are extremely powerful and are used all over the place. The idea is that you want to do something until some sort of flag or condition occurs, then stop doing the thing. I hope that makes sense.

---

Secondly, you need to learn about the input function.

```
x = input()
```

The input function is just a regular function that returns a string with the user input. If you want to make it into a number, then you have to typecast it to the type of number you want.

```
x = int(input())
```

You're already doing this. But what if you want a string?

Let's get back to your code:

```
myLevel=int(input("would you like to play level 1, 2, 3, or quit?"))
# User inputs "quit"
>> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'quit'
```

This happens because we already converted our input to an int. However, at no point are we doing any math with MyLevel. Here's a better way:

```
myLevel = input("would you like to play level 1, 2, 3, or quit?")
if myLevel == "quit":
    exit() # this exits a python program entirely.
if myLevel == "1":
    #do level 1 stuff
if myLevel == "2":
    #do level 2 stuff
if myLevel == "3":
    #do level 3 stuff
```

Our lives are made easier by not converting this variable. However, it's correct to convert the guess-a-number input() results because those need to be compared to other numbers.

---

Finally, this project is meant to teach you a very valuable lesson! Don't repeat yourself in the code. If you find yourself doing ANYTHING twice (or any number of times more than one), then use a function, loop, or other construct to condense it. We'll use your project as an example. I updated the code to get it working.

```
if myLevel == 1:
    number1= random.randit(1,10)
    guess1=int(input("guess an integer from 1 to ten"))

    # This whole while loop needs to be within the "if" statement's indented block.
    # Why? Because we only want to execute the code *if* we're on level 1.
    while number1!=guess1:
        print(str(number1) + " isn't correct.") #fixed this
        if guess1<number1:
            print("guess is too low")
            guess1=int(input("guess again! or would you like to quit?"))
        elif guess1>number1:
            print("guess is too high!")
            guess1=int(input("guess again! or would you like to quit?"))

    # The last if statement isn't needed so I took it out.
    # Why? Because if the loop ends, it's because guess1==number1. So our condition
    # always returns true. Therefore, we can just move the print statement outside of the
    # while loop.

    print("you guessed it!")
```

This is a fine start and it should be working. Now, what do we do for level 2? The first thing that comes to mind is to copy paste this whole code block... but that would be repeating ourself! We're going to reject that idea straight out because we don't repeat ourselves.

Instead, let's use a function to wrap up the core of the game into a nice little repeatable action. Functions are just repeatable actions.

```
# define a function with a variable to hold the highest possible guess
def guess(max): 
    # get a random number based on our max
    number = random.randint(1,max)

    guess = int(input("guess an integer from 1 to " + str(max)))
    while number != guess: # Guess is wrong
        if guess < number:
            print("guess is too low")
        elif guess > number:
            print("guess is too high!")

        # Since guess is wrong, we can just assume we'll always do this.
        # I removed the int() wrapper for the next step
        guess = input("guess again! or would you like to quit?")

        # Adding "quit" as an option:
        if guess == "quit":
            exit()
        else:
            guess = int(guess) # Now we can convert to int for our comparisons.


    print("you guessed it!")
```

With this defined, now we just need to call the function itself at the correct difficulty.

```
if myLevel == "1":
    guess(10)
if myLevel == "2":
    guess(100)
if myLevel == "3":
    guess(500)
```

If you're still alive after reading all this, hopefully you noticed a problem here -- we're repeating ourselves with 3 different if statements. We can do better, but that's a lesson for another day!

tl;dr:
1) Input returns a string, so you converted it to an int immediately. However, a string of "quit" is a valid choice and this will give you an error if you convert it to an int. Instead, test for "quit" first, then convert to an int if needed.
2) A while loop is for repeating something until some sort of condition is cleared. Loops and if statements can be nested within other statements. Think about when you want your code to run and honestly just practice a bit to make this more natural.
3) If you're repeating something in your code (copy/pasting similar things over and over again), strongly consider making a function or loop or something similar to do the work for you!

Answer (score 0):

For the quit it's simple. Either use `quit()`, or, if you don't want to reload the program, put everything in a `while` loop and have the quit function set it to `false`, and then `true` after a while. For the 3 levels, you could either write 3 entirely separate programs or use `if` statements to change numbers or something. I'm not sure that would work, though.

As for your `while` problem, just use `while some_variable='whatever_you_want':` and you're done.